# What's the difference between tag and semver in the NPM Doc

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-modules

To make it clear, the "tag" here is used to label a certain package in NPM as mentioned in [this doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags)

1. Is tag an alias for a semver? or another means for labeling a version?
2. Is tag required by each version release? I know there is a default "latest" and you can specify a new one. but is there always one tag  there?
3. Can I use use semver with tag together to specify the version?
   What's the syntax for doing this? for example：npm install moduleA@semver-tag
4. Is there an easy way to enumerate all semver and tags for a certain
   npm package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The difference is the same as between a guitar and a song. The former is a tool to deliver the later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As stated in the doc you posted,

> Tags are a supplement to semver

This means, you can give the users of your package more specific details. Is version 1.9.1 a beta release, stable, legacy, under development? It is just an additional string for your semver version.

2. Tags are not mandatory. if you `npm view` a package, you will see that there are versions that do not have a dist-tag related to them.
3. Yes, you can install by dist-tag. `npm install webpack@latest`
4. `npm view <packagename>`

Comment: I use "npm view react" to find a version '0.9.0-rc1' ,is it a valid semver or a tag? According to the doc, I should use either  a semver or a tag to install a package but not both and a tag shouldn't start with a digit. however, I cannot run "npm i react@rc1". Why?

Comment: _rc1_ belongs to the Version number. if you run `npm view react`, you will see a "dist-tags" property containing the tags `latest`, `next` and `dev` which **point** to specific versions in the _versions_-array.

Comment: I finally found that the "rc1" part is called pre-release number. According to the semver spec, the semantic version can include not only [major.minor.patch] part but also a pre-release number part. but the npm doc dose not mention it. Thank you!